# Is there a way to replace the 4.4.2-style emoji graphics with the Google Hangouts versions?

Tags: emoticons

I don't use emoji very often, but I did think the Google Hangouts-style emoticons were rather adorable. Following the 4.4.2 update, the graphics set used for emoji have been enabled in the stock keyboard, but in these rather unattractive cliche-looking versions which have also overridden the ones available in Hangouts. Is there any way I can get a Google Hangouts-style icon pack or something? All of the Google Play searches I've attempted returned mostly emoji keyboards which are NOT what I am looking for.

Comment: What phone are you on? Some manufacturers skin the Emoji, I'm looking at Samsung's at the moment and they're pretty dreadful. They change from the keyroard to what appears in the Hangout due to Touchwiz and its invasive uglyness!

Comment: @RossC An s3. So there's no way to change it?

Answer (score 5):

Needs root access: You can change the `AndroidEmoji.ttf` font that can be found in `/system/fonts/`. XDA has a copy of [different Emoji fonts](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2618523) you can use.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2618523 here are the attachments with the emoji from Google if you want to add to your answer

Comment: I haven't rooted my phone; is there another way to accomplish this? How do apps that add system fonts work without root access?

Comment: @AsianSquirrel No idea, but I think you wouldn't be able to replace the exact font (name) without root access. You might want to check if this works: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2479346 Please give feedback.

Comment: @geffchang The iFont app seemed like it would work if you wanted to change the system font and not necessarily the emoji font. However, a fee was required for use on non-rooted devices; I have no money, and therefore could not try it out. Interestingly enough, `NotoColorEmoji.ttf` was in the /system/fonts folder (along with the rest of the NotoSans, etc. font family),but I'm guessing `SamsungEmoji.ttf` is what is being used as the display font for emoji? There are several other fonts in the font folder, but none of them (incl. Noto) are available for selection in the  system Display options.