# How do I update the emoji set for standard messaging applications?

Tags: applications, updates, google-hangouts, emoticons

I have a basic compatibility problem with emoji: the emoji available on one Android device (Android 8.1) do not match those available on a second (Android 6.0?) in applications including the SMS messaging application or Google Hangouts. Some emoji show up as blank boxes on the receiving end.

Is there a way to update the older Android device to include newer emoji? Assume that the messaging applications such as Google Hangouts have the latest updates for their respective platforms and that the receiving device is a normal end user device that is not rooted.

Comment: Kind of related/duplicate: [Is there a way to replace the 4.4.2-style emoji graphics with the Google Hangouts versions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/74769) (need root). While some apps deliver their own emoji for consistency (e.g. [WhatsApp](https://blog.emojipedia.org/whatsapp-releases-its-own-emoji-set/)), others just depend on the system fonts.

Comment: @AndrewT. The answers to that question seem to suggest root access is required. Is that true?

Comment: Root is probably the only answer, otherwise each app developer needs to integrate [Emoji Compat](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat) into their code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue recently.

From what I gathered, emojis and non-emoji codepoints in Android are stored in separated font files.
Regular chars and any non-emoji symbols come from the system fonts, which can be edited on some systems.
Emojis, on the other hand, seem to come from a static file named "NotoColorEmoji.ttf".
The latest version of this font can be found in this [google repository](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main/fonts).

However, at this time no system API seem to allow the manipulation of this file.
So you are left with rooting the device as the only method to accomplish this update.